# Using dataprovider with conditions

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Is there way of getting data from a dataprovider based on certain condition? Something like..

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Data-Provider-Function" class="Randomclass.class")
public void parameterIntTest(Class clzz, String[] number) {
   System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + number[0]);
   System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + number[1]);
}

//This function will provide the parameter data
@DataProvider(name = "Data-Provider-Function")
public Object[][] parameterIntTestProvider(boolean evenOnly) {
            if(evenOnly)
                 return new Object[][]{};
            else
                 return new Object[][]{};
     }
```

or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

The data providers support `@Parameters` annotation where you can customize them with a fixed set of values configured in your testng.xml (hostnames, transaction isolation, etc)

Alternatively, you can introduce an utility method that generates the actual data and wrap with two distinct data-providers calling it with different parameters.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml